# Power Timer Socket IC

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification

I began using a Belkin Conserve Socket and opened it to see the assembly inside. I understand the rest of the components but there is a 6-pin IC (U1) that I can't put my finger on. Pictures are attached. Would be grateful if someone could identify it for me.

[image: photo3]
[image: Photo 1]

Comment: Likely some voltage regulator, one could probably say more with at least a partially recovered schmeatics.

Comment: The 6 vias nearby make me wonder if it isn't a MCU, perhaps some variety of PIC.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be 100% sure but my guess would be a [PIC10F222-I/OT](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001270F.pdf) which if you check the datasheet has a marking code of 22NN where NN is an alphanumeric traceability code. Looking at the marking orientation in the datasheet and the small dot visible pin one would be at the top-right in your photo. So that gives:

- Pins 1, 3 and 6 that are required for programming go to the strip of six through-holes that I suspect are for in-system programming.
- Pin 5 which is Vdd seems to be decoupled to ground.
- Pin 4 which is a GPIO not required for programming seems to run directly towards the relay. That's a 24V relay so I assume they're a transistor driver on the other side of the board not shown. Picking a pin not used during programming would also be a good choice for a relay output.

Pin 2 which is ground is hard to follow but maybe you could confirm that's connected to the bottom of C2 and all the above matches up with the parts of the board not shown.

Comment: I agree with you, C2 and pin2 are connected, here is better [image](http://postimg.org/image/4pcftcm4d/). [Original image](https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5524/10184020596_320ba22de4_b.jpg).